# Rabbit spring cloud stream bind topics to single queue

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

Is it possible to bind multiple topics from an exchange to single queue?
For example I have producer which declares an exchange and sends three topics **log.verbose**, **log.info**, **log.error**

And I would like to have two consumers which declare own queue and bind to exchange.
First consumer subscribes first two topics **log.verbose** and **log.info** and another one subscribes all topics.

Is it possible to define config for consumer 1 something like this?

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=log
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=log.info,log.verbose
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not currently do it through property configuration, but you can add the second binding yourself, either manually on the management UI, or by adding `Exchange`, `Queue` and `Binding` `@Bean`s to the application. You can't simply add the second `@Binding` bean since the queue won't exist yet when the `RabbitAdmin` (when the application is first started and no queue exists).

See [Configuring the broker](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration) in the Spring AMQP reference manual.

This technique won't work for anonymous consumers (no `...group` property specified for the `input`) since the queue name is not known.